# DTO constructors when nullable reference type enabled

Tags: c#, oop, nullable-reference-types

Some scenarios in my code is that I have to get an object from an external service, deserialize it and return it to the front end. My code includes nullable reference from C# 8 and compiler complains about such DTOs without constructor. Any of such fields cannot be null if entity is real.

I don't need someone to be able to create such objects manually, but when using the deserializer I need the type to have an empty constructor and fields with public setters. Because of this I have to write a lot of ugly code. Is there a better approach in this scenario or some syntactic sugar to reduce the infra-structural code?

```
public class AddressRF
{
    public AddressRF() // used implicitly
    {
        ZipCode = null!;
        RegionCode = null!;
        RegionName = null!;
        District = null!;
        City = null!;
        Settlement = null!;
        Street = null!;
        House = null!;
        Bulk = null!;
        Flat = null!;
        KladrCode = null!;
        HouseRaw = null!;
        BulkRaw = null!;
        FlatRaw = null!;
    }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; } 
    public string RegionCode { get; set; } 
    public Toponym RegionName { get; set; } 
    public Toponym District { get; set; } 
    public Toponym City { get; set; } 
    public Toponym Settlement { get; set; } 
    public Toponym Street { get; set; } 
    public Toponym House { get; set; } 
    public Toponym Bulk { get; set; } 
    public Toponym Flat { get; set; } 
    public string KladrCode { get; set; } 
    public string HouseRaw { get; set; } 
    public string BulkRaw { get; set; } 
    public string FlatRaw { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few options

1 - Declare properties as Nullable

```
public string? ZipCode { get; set; }
```

2 - Add nullable disable around the constructor

```
#nullable disable
        public AddressRF() // used implicitly
        {
        }
#nullable enable
```

3 - Set the value on the property level

```
public string ZipCode { get; set; } = string.Empty; // or = null!
```

Comment: `= null!` to supress the warning also